# Angular displays ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined although I see it is defined

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

This is the code in the template:

```
<li
        *ngFor="let option of optionList"
        [attr.value]="option.value"
        [hidden]="!option.visible"
        (click)="liClicked(option, $event)"
        (mouseenter)="addNameToLabelOnHover && false ? liHovered(option, $event) : ''"
        (mouseleave)="addNameToLabelOnHover ? liLeft(option, $event) : ''"
        [ngStyle]="{ width: option.addNameToLabel ? 'max-content' : '' }"
        [title]="addFullNameTooltip ? option.name : ''"
        [class.hiddenContainerSpace]="!isListOpen"
        class="valuesList main-option-list-option"
    >
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            [disabled]="isEuSelected"
            (click)="cbClicked(option, $event)"
            [(ngModel)]="option.selected"
        />

        <span class="option-label" (mouseenter)="addNameToLabelOnHover ? liHovered(option, $event) : ''"
            >{{ option.label }}
            {{ displayFullOptionNameAsLabel || option.addNameToLabel ? "(" + option.name + ")" : "" }}</span
        >

        <input
            *ngIf="addCoupledCheckbox"
            class="ingredient-checkbox"
            type="checkbox"
            [disabled]="isEuSelected"
            (click)="coupledCbClicked(option, $event)"
            [(ngModel)]="coupledOptionList[option.label].selected"
        />
    </li>
```

In the first input and span, everything works fine, but the second input breaks because of the error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'selected' of undefined
```

I am assuing this has something to do with too much nesting here for the ngModel, but I would love to know what is wrong adn can this be done? Thanks everyone for any suggestions!

Comment: Output your json next to the problematic element and see the json like so `{{ option | json}}`

Comment: What @ImmortalDude said plus this looks suspicious:
`[(ngModel)]="coupledOptionList[option.label].selected"`